# How to have a thread safe data in scala

Tags: scala, thread-safety

Newbie in Scala here.

I'm doing a simple project in Scala with a simple web service, so I don't want to use a full blown db.

All my application is immutable. But I don't know how to do the "data" part.

My web service has GET and some POST and PUT. So I'd like my data to be:
- stored in memory
- thread safe (so many concurrent PUT won't mess it
- immmutable? (I'm new to the concept, but I guess is not possible)

I thought of an object like:

```
object UserContainer {
    var users: List[User] = initializeUsers()

    def editUser(...) = ...
    def addUser(...) = ...
}
```

But it's not thread safe, neither immutable. I found that I can use "Actors" or "synchronize" for this.
How should I approach?

Comment: You could use java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference. Write a Scala wrapper for that class and then use that to store an immutable Vector of User objects.

Answer (score 2):

The primary concurrency abstraction provided by Actors is to provide threadsafe access to *mutable* state in a *asynchronous* and *non-blocking* fashion. Looks like that is your use case.

Some options for building build web services you should look at Spray.io or akka-http - both of which are based on Akka actors. However, creating actors (esp. using Akka) needs an `ActorSystem` which some argue is heavyweight. Additionally,  actors (as of today) are not typed, so you don't get the type safety of Scala.